# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream) returns null - Android

Tags: android, bitmap, fileinputstream, bitmapfactory

I have a problem with the following code in Android Studio:

```
try {
     FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dirPhoto);
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
     vwImagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (SecurityException io) {

} catch (FileNotFoundException io) {

}
```

The fileInputStream was found, but method `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream)` return a null.

```
dirPhoto=/data/data/com.example.leandro.application/files/pic_20170316104409.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason FileInputStream could not decode the address contained in dirPhoto (even if it existed). I solved it by creating the address with the method:
"myContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURE‌​S).getAbsolutePath()‌​"

Thank you very much!